# How to install p4 on fedora?

Tags: linux

I want to install p4 (Perforce Command-Line Client (p4) x86-64) on fedora. But the download page of the executables directs to a page that belongs to "Helix".

Is there any suitable wget link to download p4 the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact wget command but do any of the files here help...

http://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/bin.linux26x86_64/

The main page for version 16.2 is here...

http://cdist2.perforce.com/perforce/r16.2/

Regards...